# Apache Ignite cache atomicity mode mismatch

Tags: java, ignite

After creating cache like this

```
CacheConfiguration<String, String> cacheCfg = new CacheConfiguration<>("cache");
cacheCfg.setCacheMode(CacheMode.REPLICATED);
cacheCfg.setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.TRANSACTIONAL);
igniteCfg.setCacheConfiguration(cacheCfg);
Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(cfg);

ignite.getOrCreateCache(cacheCfg)
```

The exception happens to be:

```
Caused by: org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Cache atomicity mode mismatch (fix cache atomicity mode in cache configuration or set -DIGNITE_SKIP_CONFIGURATION_CONSISTENCY_CHECK=true system property) [cacheName=xac-banking-accounts-warmup-cache, localAtomicityMode=TRANSACTIONAL, remoteAtomicityMode=ATOMIC, rmtNodeId=8a8da4fb-d561-4e10-8b67-1b5c8b9d941d]
```

In debug mode I discovered in code to sets of configuration:

1. GridCacheAttributes rmtAttr
2. GridCacheAttributes locAttr

So I think I should be able to configure the rmt (remote) cache
but I cannot find how or where.

Are you aware of any other way to configure the remote cache ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't change the atomicity mode after the cache has been created. Your configuration needs to be the same as on the remote node.

On the other hand, if you're trying to change the type, you'll have to create a new cache with the new configuration and copy the data over. (Which isn't ideal, but that's how it currently works.)